# psql: server closed the connection unexepectedly

Tags: sql, postgresql, cmd

I've been trying to run this batch file that goes through the Postgre DB Server and run two different sql files, as shown below:

```
set PGPASSWORD=blah
cls
@echo on
"C:\Progra~1\pgAdmin III\1.16\psql" -d [db name] -h [server name] -p 5432 -U postgres -f C:\query1.sql
"C:\Progra~1\pgAdmin III\1.16\psql" -d [db name] -h [server name] -p 5432 -U postgres -f C:\query2.sql
```

But the issue comes that sometimes I will get the following error for either the command for query1 or query2:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

This only happens sometimes, so I'm not entirely sure why it is happening. Can someone explain why this is the case and if there's a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Update: I also get the same error SOMETIMES when trying to open the remote server in the actual Postgre application: "An error has occured: "server closed the connection unexpectedly 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request."

I also get this Guru Hint thing right after I click out of the error popup:

Database encoding
The database VA-trac is created to store data using the SQL_ASCII encoding. This encoding is defined for 7 bit characters only; the meaning of characters with the 8th bit set (non-ASCII characters 127-255) is not defined. Consequently, it is not possible for the server to convert the data to other encodings. 
If you're storing non-ASCII data in the database, you're strongly encouraged to use a proper database encoding representing your locale character set to take benefit from the automatic conversion to different client encodings when needed. If you store non-ASCII data in an SQL_ASCII database, you may encounter weird characters written to or read from the database, caused by code conversion problems. This may cause you a lot of headache when accessing the database using different client programs and drivers. 
For most installations, Unicode (UTF8) encoding will provide the most flexible capabilities.

Regardless, the server still opens up afterward and I'm able to access the database from that point on.

Comment: Do you get the same effect when you log in interactively (i.e. without the SQL script)? What does PostgreSQL's log file say about the terminated connections?

Comment: PostgreSQL version? What happens if you use the `psql` from PostgreSQL's `bin` directory rather than one bundled in PgAdmin-III? Is there a firewall involved anywhere?

Comment: Check my update above, my version is 1.16.1

Comment: If the connection aborts randomly I'd suspect network issues. Again, what does the log on the PostgreSQL server say about these terminated connections? And Craig was asking for the *PostgreSQL* version, not the *PgAdmin* version.

Comment: It turns out it is because there was a mismatch between the postgre SQL version between my local and the server, installing the same version of PostgreSQL in my computer fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I had this same problem but when I tried to connect to the DB using ADO in an Excel macro to run a query and populate the record set in Excel.  I ran VACUUM/ANALYZE, reran the macro, and the record set populated in under 5 seconds.

Answer (score 46):

Leaving this here for info,

This error can also be caused if PostgreSQL server is on another machine and is **not listening on external interfaces**.

To debug this specific problem, you can follow theses steps:

- Look at your postgresql.conf, `sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`
- Add this line: `listen_addresses = '*'`
- Restart the service `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

(Note, the commands above are for ubuntu. Other linux distro or OS may have different path to theses files)

Note: using `'*'` for listening addresses will listen on all interfaces.  If you do `'0.0.0.0'` then it'll listen for all ipv4 and if you do `'::'` then it'll listen for all ipv6.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: This line `listen_addresses = '*'` exists by default on official Dockerized images on https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. How could the connected be terminated if it was never established?

Comment: For 64bit Windows, postgresql.conf is under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<VERSION>\data`

Answer (score 32):

It turns out it is because there was a mismatch between the postgre SQL version between my local and the server, installing the same version of PostgreSQL in my computer fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: August 2020. This is still relevant.

Comment: how can I match them together?

Comment: Just one example: pgAdmin 4.28 won't connect to any postgres server 12.4. If you downgrade to pgAdmin 4.27 you will be able to connect to 12.4. Unbelievable...

Comment: How do you find out which pgAdmin version can connect to which postgres version?

Comment: i did installed the same version on my machine but the problem still there.

Comment: Still relevant in October 2022. For me, having matching major versions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it was because I set up the IP configuration wrongly in pg_hba.conf, that sits inside data folder in Windows.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24            md5
```

I mistakenly entered (copied-pasted :-) ) 192.168.0.0 instead of 192.168.1.0.

Comment: For 64-bit Windows, pg_hba.conf is under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\VERSION\data\`

Comment: Possible Error Message: State: 08001 Native error: 101 Message: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "a.b.c.d", user "postgres", database "template1", SSL off

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was making an connection through pgAdmin with ssh tunneling and set to host field ip address but it was necessary to set `localhost`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, i'm using Postgresql 9.2.24 and solution was this (pg_hba.conf):

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

For remote connections use **trust**. Combined with (as mentioned above)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Comment: Please also note that `listen_addresses = '*'` doesn't belongs to `pg_hba.conf`, instead it belongs to `postgresql.conf`, by default, list_addresses is set to all (*). https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A76B25F2823E954C9E45E32FA49D70EC9199AF46@mail.corp.perceptron.com

Comment: This was definitely the required solution for me -- adding this line to `pg_hba.conf` in addition to the `listen_addresses = '*'` line in `postgresql.conf`

Comment: This isn't secure, though, so I don't suggest you use this in production.  It might indicate that indeed there is a networking allowance issue in pg_hba.conf to be worked out.

Answer (score 5):

this is an old post but...

just surprised that nobody talk about pg_hba file as it can be a good reason to get this error code.

Check here for those who forgot to configure it:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 1):

If your Postgres was working and suddenly you encountered with this error, my problem was resolved just by restarting Postgres service or container.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker make sure you are not using the same port in another service, in my case i was mistakenly using the same port for both PostgreSQL and Redis.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying use ssh tunnel connection through pgAdmin4 and before that set `AllowTcpForwarding no` in server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. But it should be `AllowTcpForwarding yes`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connection through a SSH tunnel, this could mean you did a wrong port redirect on the target machine, check the log of the sshd on your jumpbox to see if this is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting a password for the user first.

In terminal

```sql
sudo -u <username> psql

ALTER USER <username> PASSWORD 'SetPassword';
# ALTER ROLE

\q
```

In pgAdmin

```
**Connection**

Host name/address: 127.0.0.1
Port: 5432
Maintenance database: postgres
username: postgres
password: XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case my postgres rds instance was stopped...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a discrepancy between postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf

pg_hba.conf had a hostssl rule

```
hostssl   all           all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

and

postgresql.conf had

```
ssl = off
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my Postgres.

As it's only happenning to one of my Django models save() method (a huge one), I blame the size of the record being inserted.