# How do I connect to postgres database in Rstudio (MacOS)?

Tags: r, database, connection, dbi, rpostgresql

I'm trying to connect from RStudio on my Mac to a PostgreSQL database.
The following code chunk works successfully on the Windows and Mac RStudio installs of my colleagues.

```
blah.blah.rds.amazonaws.comblah.blah.rds.amazonaws.com"
dbport <- 5432
dbuser <- "my_username"
dbname <- "my_db_name"
dbpw <- "my_password"
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                  dbname = dbname,
                  host = dbhost,
                  port = dbport,
                  user = dbuser,
                  password = dbpw
)
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table LIMIT 10;")
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

But using my machine I receive the following error from the `dbConnect()` call.

```
# Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request:
```

I can connect to the db in question through a client like PGAdmin and from python. Any ideas what the problem could be?
My `sessionInfo` is:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] RPostgres_1.2.0 DBI_1.1.0      
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_1.1-15.2    compiler_3.6.3  hms_0.5.3       tools_3.6.3     Rcpp_1.0.4.6    bit64_0.9-7     vctrs_0.2.4     knitr_1.28     
 [9] blob_1.2.1      xfun_0.13       pkgconfig_2.0.3 rlang_0.4.5
```

Comment: Is this similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934364/psql-server-closed-the-connection-unexepectedly

Comment: Second the hint by user @9314197 -- was original maintainer of RPostgreSQL as well as of another piece of software connecting to PostgreSQL.  You *must* allow for network connection; the fact that `psql` connects is not suffcient.  In other words, it is likely the _server_ side not the macOS client side.

Comment: Why should other users at the same time be connected through same clients/other clients (RStudio via `RPostgres` on macOS and Windows) whilst OP cannot form a connection? What other diagnostics can sought to identify issue with server and the OP's client install?

Comment: That would indeed be odd. On new machines, or after upgrades, I usually set up the host/network settings for the PostgreSQL server such that another machine on my subnet (say, laptop) could connect.  Then my server generally could too. I could paste my settings if it is considered helpful -- been doing this on the home linux server since the 1990s ...

Comment: Oh, here is another one.  Sometimes the `id` tools is used to check if user name on server and client is the same.  For that the server calls back to the requesting client _which must have the appropriate RPC program installed_.  That behavior can be turned off in the server but is, if memory serves, on my default.